# Andengine reducing sprite quality?

Tags: andengine, png

I have a problem with bandings using andengine. When painting a picture on PC and uploading it to my phone, they look exactly the same. But as soon as I use that bitmap (PNG) in Andengine, I have bandings (big color steps).

Now I know that my display is capable of displaying the image right and I know how to us dithering but it bothers me. Does anyone know how to disable this quality reduction in Andengine?

Comment: Post the code you are using to load the texture. If you are using the RGBA_4444 type of texture, that might be one of the reasons.

Comment: textureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 300, 300, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);

Answer (score 1):

You are using `TextureOptions.DEFAULT`. If you inspect the `TextureOptions` class, you will notice that:

```
public static final TextureOptions DEFAULT = NEAREST;
```

Which means your textures are being resampled using nearest-neighbor interpolation. AndEngine will automatically scale your game to the phone's resolution. If you are not scaling in steps of 2 (e.g. your resolution of choice is 800x480 and your phone's resolution is 1280x768) it will create "bandings".

Try `TextureOptions.BILINEAR` or `TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA`.

You can also try whether the following option improves the banding:

`engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);`

Comment: I already tried both of them and it didnt change anything. i am using a camera size of 1600x960. and the ratio is not the same as my phone. but even changing it to half of it wont make the bandings disappear

Comment: @user42152 I've added another option to improve the sprite quality to the answer.

Comment: yeah thanks. changing the TextureOptions didnt change anything. I am using dithering now as i didnt seem to have any performance issues.